# Linux ssh bash fork retry: no child processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sh

I am on arch linux, accessing an account on a server over SSH. I have run a bash script containing recursion that results in an infinite loop of "no such file or directory" which continues despite any interrupt command ctrl C etc, it is totally uninterruptible. This eventually results in an endless stream of bash: fork: No child processes. I cannot execute any commands whilst this happens, and when it stops with "Resource temporarily unavailable", i am unable to execute any commands to kill the script because "bash: fork: No child processes" starts up again. I have no idea what to do, any help?

[ps doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2de6.jpg)

Comment: well, quite hard to help with nothing concrete to see nor experiment...

Comment: Find and kill the script that is initiating all the forks. `ps aux | grep myprogram` && `kill <pid of myprogram>`

Comment: ps doesn't work

Comment: don't know what to do, only kill works, so i need the PID, and ps doesnt work, nor pkill

Comment: Try Ctrl+Z rather than Ctr+C.

Comment: Also, you may try to run `ps` as `sudo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you've caused a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). You can try the methods [here](https://superuser.com/questions/168804/how-do-i-kill-a-forkbomb-process) to stop it, but you'll most likely end up needing to reboot.

Comment: This is the solution from redhat https://access.redhat.com/solutions/543503

Comment: I was able to avoid a restart by using systemctl to stop some services and buy me time to run ps to find the culprit... a run away cronjob

Answer (score 16):

Run `kill -9 -1` from the user login that caused the forkbomb . No need to reboot.
*PS: Consult your seniors before running it on Prod server*

Comment: this helped me on hostinger

Comment: thanks, dude... I owe you a cup of coffee

Comment: *CAUTION:* Dont run it by root user otherwise WHM and all running sites will be down.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) ps faux  (find PID and place in second command)
2) kill [PID]


If any virus attack then again this process come so you need to enable virus scanner on cpanel and scan and remove.

Important:
Hosting providers must install the following services for this interface to appear:

The ClamAV Scanner plugin in WHM’s Manage Plugins interface (WHM >> Home >> cPanel >> Manage Plugins).
The Exim Mail Server service on the server in WHM’s Service Manager interface (WHM >> Home >> Service Configuration >> Service Manager).
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `ps faux` (you might need to run it from other user or with `sudo`) and search for the offending process (may look like a big branch of the tree)

If needed, kill the process via its PID