# Linux bash gives fork retry no child processes error

Tags: linux, unix, memory

I'm running a Nodejs app in Linux server (shared hosting server).
Terminal gives this error after one day from running app.
I run app then after one day by this command:

```
ps aux
```

the result is:

```
user   5435  1.0  0.0   9916  1820 pts/0    S    16:50   0:00 /bin/bash -l
user   5752  0.0  0.0  49844  1684 pts/0    R+   16:50   0:00 ps aux
user  13658  0.0  0.1 1155556 36060 ?       Sl   05:15   0:06 lsnode:/home1/user/node-server/
user  32346  0.0  0.1 1091012 37944 ?       Sl   Jul04   0:05 lsnode:/home1/user/node-server/
user  32346  0.0  0.1 1091012 37944 ?       Sl   Jul04   0:05 daemon pm2 bash/.pm2
```

I see 2 node apps running and after this i give this from terminal:

```
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash-4.2$
```

I have no cron inside my app. how can I solve this 2 months problem! please help me...

Comment: Instead of `ps aux`, try `ps -eLf` and see if that shows you a large number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that you reached some limit (too many processes) and the `bash` can no longer create any process.

The error message "No child processes" is probably the result of calling `waitpid` after a failed `fork`. The real error should be "Resource temporarily unavailable". (There seems to be a bug in some `bash` versions that try `waitpid` without restoring the `errno` value.)

Without seeing the source code of your application it is impossible to give a more specific answer.

See also  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205016/330217 or [Linux ssh bash fork retry: no child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47143093/10622916)

BTW: I don't think the output of `ps aux` is correct. I would expect to see much more processes.

Comment: these are the outputs of cPanel terminal that installed in shared hosting service. I'm running a node app in that and the real problem is after a day i see 2 same apps and after 4 days i see 8 same node apps that running. then bash gives these error.

Comment: @akyman Please add all background information **to your question**. Please also show the output of the command in Mark Plotnick's comment. In case you have many threads, the code of your application might also be relevant.

Comment: hey! I have solved this problem by setting a timeout to auto exiting in node js app. thanks!